# Return bool or integer from a method depending on condition

Tags: java, return

The very basic program of **pop**'ng a value from Stack in DS :

```
public int pop()
{
    if(!isEmpty())
    {
        int pop_val = myArray[topIndex];
        topIndex--;
        return pop_val;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        System.exit(0); /* stop the program execution*/
        return 4; /* did this just to avoid the error*/
    }
}
```

**Problem :** As you can see,method is supposed to return an `int` type value **but** i just want to print or return a false if stack is empty.

**Question :**

- Is it possible to return different types of return value in java
  based on conditions ??? and
- Is there a better workaround to solve such problem instead of what i am trying in my code??

---

**P.S :** *Please don't go on my Rep before answering, m hell **Noob** in `java`*

Comment: You should use exception.

Comment: Stacks commonly throw an exception if you try to pop from an empty stack.

Comment: You can use `Integer` as return type and return null when stack is empty.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : actually, m trying to learn things by coding methods for all cases...so, wanted to handle this through some method only!!

Comment: @SswaterShi you can post that as answer. In fact, it would be easier returning `null` instead in order to later move this collection into a generic form.

Comment: I think you need to implement a `peak()` method.

Comment: The [documented behavior of Stack.pop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#pop%28%29) is to throw an [EmptyStackException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html). Doing anything else would be counter-intuitive to anyone used to the default [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, you can't return different types of object from methods (unless they have a common superclass, in which case this is possible).
2. If I were you, I would throw a custom `Exception` when the stack is empty:

For example:

```
public int pop() throws EmptyStackException {
 ...
}
```

Note: If you don't want to use `Exception`(s), you can define an invalid return value, for example `-1`.

```
public int pop() {
    ...

    return -1; /* did this just to avoid the error*/
}
```

Comment: so if i do `return -1`,what exactly happens....?? won't this invalid return throw an error?? *asking because not able to understand how java handles this case*

Comment: In this case you will have to handle manually the cases in which it returns `-1` (e.g. check the returned value and if it's `-1` then you will have indicated an error). As I said, I prefer the `Exception` approach.

Comment: You should use the built in [EmptyStackException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html). See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556621/return-bool-or-integer-from-a-method-depending-on-condition#comment32556222_21556621) for the reasons _why_.

Comment: @kocko : ok...even i thought of this logic, but assume, my stack also has a value `-1` stored in it, in that case, i would not be able to make out whether this `-1` has been returned from the stack or `invalid return`...do i make sense?? :\

Comment: You've just nailed the reason why I prefer the Exception approach. :)

Comment: @JesseWebb : thankx for the reference, its helpful!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I would throw an *exception* to indicate that the stack is empty, however, if you don't want to do that, you can `return` 0 and it'll be the caller responsibility to arise an error or whatever he wants if the stack is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Integer` as return type and return `null` when stack is empty.

Thanks to  @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: `Type mismatch : cannot convert from null to int`

Comment: You need to test whether it is `null` first, if not, you can convert `Integer` to `int`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for a method to have different return types.

You should break your functionlity into 2 seperate methods: 1) check if the list is empty, 2) pop from the list.

```
public boolean hasContent () {
    //Check to see if there is something to pop()
}

public int pop() {
    //Pop off the stack
    //Throw an error or return some sort of default empty value if there is nothing to pop
}

...

//usage
if(stack.hasContent()) {
  stack.pop()
}
```